# Multiple columns instead of 1

Tags: sql

I'm trying to list multiple columns for a series of 3 tables where it can identify multiple owners for a single house, however I'm trying to figure out what to search for to help me accomplish what I'm looking for.

```
Inventory
--------------------
ID | House Address |
--------------------
1  | 123 Main St   |
--------------------
2  | 436 East St   |
--------------------

Contacts
----------------
ID | Name      |
----------------
1  | Billy Bob |
----------------
2  | Mary Ann  |
----------------
3  | Gilligan  |
----------------
4  | Skipper   |
----------------

Owners
-----------------------
InvID  |  ContactsID  |
-----------------------
1      | 2            |
-----------------------
2      | 1            |
-----------------------
2      | 3            |
-----------------------
2      | 4            |
----------------------- 

Ideal Result
----------------------------------------------
Address     | Owner1    | Owner2   | Owner3  |
----------------------------------------------
123 Main St | Billy Bob | Gilligan | Skipper |
----------------------------------------------
436 East St | Mary Ann  |          |         |
----------------------------------------------
```

I've tried Joining these tables however it doesn't give the expected output.  If someone could point me in a direction to research I would be glad to find the answer myself however at this point I'm scratching my head for what I'm looking for.

**One solution that I've tried:**

```
Select 
    Inventory.Address,
    Contacts.FirstName + ' ' + Contacts.LastName AS 'Owner',
    Contacts.Phone
From Inventory
LEFT JOIN Owners
ON Owners.InventoryID = Inventory.ID
LEFT JOIN Contacts
ON Contacts.ID = Owners.ContactID
```

This gives me all the information that I need, just not in the format I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: You need to PIVOT result, specify database you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following query with nested derived tables that uses a calculated row number to present Owners 1-3 in separate columns.

This should work as a general solution across most RDMSs as it uses ANSI SQL syntax not restricted to any specific `Pivot()`, `Over()`, or `CTE()` functions:

```
SELECT 
   Address, 
   Max([Owner_1]) As Owner1,
   Max([Owner_2]) As Owner2,
   Max([Owner_3]) As Owner3
FROM
  (SELECT Address,
         CASE RowNumber = 1 THEN [Name] END As Owner_1,
         CASE RowNumber = 2 THEN [Name] END As Owner_2,
         CASE RowNumber = 3 THEN [Name] END As Owner_3
  FROM 
       (SELECT Owners.InvID, Owners.[Contacts ID], Inventory.Address, Contacts.Name,
              (SELECT Count(*) FROM Owners t1 
               WHERE t1.[Contacts ID] <= Owners.[Contacts ID] 
               AND t1.InvID = Owners.InvID) As RowNumber    
       FROM Owners 
       LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Owners.InvID = Inventory.ID 
       LEFT JOIN Contacts ON Owners.[Contacts ID] = Contacts.ID
  ) As dT1
) As dt2
GROUP BY Address;
```

With Output as the following:

```
Address      Owner1     Owner2      Owner3
123 Main St  Mary Ann       
436 East St  Billy Bob  Gilligan    Skipper
```